# Provider isn't notified when users sign up

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter-provider, state-management

## Context

I am trying to build an app, using **Flutter**, which requires the users to **sign up** and/or **sign in**.
Using a provider, I was able to determine at each launch of the app if the user was already signed in or not, thus showing respectively the `MainScreen`  or the `SignInScreen`, as you can see from the code below.

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(Stuff());
}

class Stuff extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider<FirebaseUser>.value(value: AuthService().onAuthChanged),
      ],
      child: Consumer<FirebaseUser>(builder: (context, user, _) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Stuff',
          home:  user != null ? MainScreen() : SignInScreen(),
          routes: {
            '/main_screen' : (context) => MainScreen(),
            '/signup_screen': (context) => SignUpScreen(),
            '/signin_screen': (context) => SignInScreen(),
          },
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

where AuthService for now is just the following:

```dart
class AuthService{
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  Stream<FirebaseUser> get onAuthChanged => _firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged;
}
```

If the user is not signed in, then the`SignInScreen` is shown, and after the sign in process the `StreamProvider` is notified correctly and the `home` property of the `MaterialApp` updates automatically showing the `MainScreen`.

## Problem

When users get to the `SignInScreen` they have the choice to either **log in** or get to another the `SignUpScreen` to **sign up** ([app screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1Zqn.png)), like this:

```
GestureDetector(
    child: Text('Sign Up.'),
     onTap: () {
       Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/signup_screen');
     },
),
```

If they choose to sign in, when they're done, the `home` is correctly updated and the `MainScreen` is shown as I said above. But if they choose to sign up, **when they're done, nothing happens.** All listeners are notified, but the `StreamProvider` doesn't receive this notification. The only reason I can think of for this behavior, is that the SignUpScreen is outside the scope of the Provider, but the widget tree seems to suggets that it is.

[Widget Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9QRn.png)

It it possibile that the problem is `pushReplacementNamed`?

P.S: I should mention that the `GestureDetector` is part of the following method that I pass to the `appBar` property of `Scaffold`.

```dart
  PreferredSize _buildAppBar() {
    return PreferredSize(
      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.18),
      child: Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
            maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.18),
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 45.0, right: 45.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text('Sign In'),
            SizedBox(
              height: 2.5,
            ),
            Row(
                children: [
                  Text('Have an account already?'),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 4.0,
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    child: Text('Sign In.'),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/signin_screen');
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is because you don't notify `Stuff` widget when user signs in. You can wrap it a `Streambuilder` in order to listen to AuthState changes like this.

```
class Stuff extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
       Provider<AuthService>(create: (_) => AuthService()),
      ],
      child: Consumer<AuthService>(builder: (context, auth, _) {
        return StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(ctx,AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> snapshot)=> MaterialApp(
          title: 'Stuff',
          home: snapshot.data!= null &&  snapshot.data.user != null ? MainScreen() : SignInScreen(),
          routes: {
            '/main_screen' : (context) => MainScreen(),
            '/signup_screen': (context) => SignUpScreen(),
            '/signin_screen': (context) => SignInScreen(),
          },
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I did try this solution, but it didn't work. Also, the StreamBuilder kinda defeats the purpose of the Multiprovider I think.